# dropdownlist not recognising listitem

Tags: c#, asp.net, drop-down-menu

i have a dropdownlist whose filling is done by th function shown below-:

```
public void filldropdown()
{
    MySqlConnection conn = new MySqlConnection(connectionString);
    conn.Open();
    string query = "select * from category";
    MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(query,conn);
    MySqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
    if(dr.HasRows)
    {
        DropDownList1.Items.Add(new ListItem("---select---","null"));
        while(dr.Read())
        {
            DropDownList1.DataSource = dr;
            DropDownList1.DataTextField = "name";
            DropDownList1.DataValueField = "id";
            DropDownList1.DataBind();
        }
    }
    conn.Close();
}
```

the dropdownlist in aspx is -:

```
<asp:DropDownList OnSelectedIndexChanged="showlabel" AutoPostBack="true"    ID="DropDownList1" runat="server">
        <asp:ListItem Text="---select---" Value="null"></asp:ListItem>
    </asp:DropDownList>
```

i just don't know how the hell on earth does the first item is coming from database not "---select---"

thnx for your time.

Comment: instead of add use insert

Comment: i have used insert, that also not working

Comment: have you tried setting Append databound items as suggested by pattermeister?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to set the [AppendDataBoundItems](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.listcontrol.appenddatabounditems.aspx) property of your DropdownList to be true. Otherwise, the databind will clear the existing values.

Comment: sorry for the delay in accepting answer, its saying you can't accept the answer in 7 minutes

Answer (score 1):

You've changed the DataSource:

```
        DropDownList1.DataSource = dr;
        DropDownList1.DataTextField = "name";
        DropDownList1.DataValueField = "id";
        DropDownList1.DataBind();
```

When you change the DataSource to `dr` it will erase your current `---select---` item (As expected).

You need to add it after the `DataSource` has been bound.

```
 DropDownList1.Items.Insert(0, new ListItem("---- select ----", 0));
 DropDownList1.SelectedIndex = 0;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
    public void filldropdown()
    {
        MySqlConnection conn = new MySqlConnection(connectionString);
        conn.Open();
        string query = "select * from category";
        MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(query, conn);

        MySqlDataAdapter da = new MySqlDataAdapter(cmd);
        DataSet ds=new DataSet();
        da.Fill(ds);
        DropDownList DropDownList1 = new DropDownList();
        DropDownList1.DataSource = ds;
        DropDownList1.DataTextField = "name";
        DropDownList1.DataValueField = "id";
        DropDownList1.DataBind();
        DropDownList1.Items.Insert(0,new ListItem("---select---", "null"));
        conn.Close();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

There are ways to add item to a databound dropdown, like I am using Insert which specifies that where to Insert (at which position).

```
DropDownList1.Items.Insert(1, "-- Select --");
```